# Derivative of a curve of a manifold

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

I have a bit confused about the derivative of a curve on a manifold,
Let $S$ be a manifold and $[\xi^i]$ be its global coordinate, let $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to S$ be a curve of a manifold and we have a coordinate map $\phi: S\to \phi(S)\subseteq\mathbb{R^n}$.So to talk about the differentiability of curve $\gamma$ we talk about the differentiability of $\phi\circ\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^n}$.
so now we have $\frac{d}{dt}\phi\circ\gamma(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\phi(\gamma^1(t),....,\gamma^n(t))$ where $\gamma^i(t)=\xi^i\circ\gamma$,
in my view this differentiability is equal to
$\frac{d}{dt}\phi\circ\gamma(t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi^i}\phi(\gamma(t))\frac{d}{dt}\gamma(t)$.Is this expression is correct?

Comment: You are confusing lots of things. $\gamma^i = \xi^i\circ \gamma$ is a function from an interval to $\Bbb R$, so you already know how to differentiate it. No need to invoke the chain rule or partial derivatives.

Comment: but here I am differentiating $\phi\circ\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^n}$ and here $\phi:S\to\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: In fact, the fact you are referring to $\xi^i$ and $\pi$ without them being related in any way makes little to no sense

Comment: suppose we have $w(x,y)=f(x(t),y(t))$ and if we want to calculate $\frac{d}{dt}w=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$? So I am applying the same logic here.

Comment: Still this does not really make sense to me: what is the chart you choose to compute, is it $\phi$, or is it $\xi=(\xi^1,\ldots,\xi^n)$? (Addendum: in my previous comment, replace $\pi$ with $\phi$)

Comment: Here chart is $S$ and $\phi$ is a coordinate map and $[\xi^i]$ are the coordinate system for $S$,so this coordinate system is defined globally on $S$ not locally.

Comment: This is too confused. You don't need two coordinates systems / charts. $S$ is not a chart but a manifold right? What is the link between $\phi$ and $\xi^i$ is any? If no, why use two of them?

Comment: since $S$ is a manifold so it does not have a coordinate system in general $\phi: S\to \phi(S)\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ is a homomorphism which provides a coordinate system to $S$.What's the confusion here??

Comment: It is your question which says some confusing things and is not really well stated I guess. Maybe someone will understand it, but I assure you I tried to and can't understand what is "$[\xi^i]$ its global coordinate system" then "let $\phi\colon S\to \Bbb R^n$ be a chart" etc. Maybe it is all clear for you but the way it is formulated is really, really confusing.

Comment: let me try to clear it,we have a n-dimensional manifold $S$ and suppose there is a point $p\in S$,now we have a coordinate map which is $\phi:S\to\mathbb{R^n}$(homomorphism), that is ,for $p\in S$ we have a $\phi(p)\in \mathbb{R^n}$,here $\phi(p)=(\xi^1,.....,\xi^n)$,and each $\xi^i:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$ so now we have a coordinate on $S$ which is $(\xi^1,...,\xi^n)$, so here we have a coordinate chart $(S,\phi)$,is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, it is clear now: $\xi$ is the coordinate system associated to $\phi$. If you read your question again, you will see that this is not clear at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation
$$
\phi(\gamma^1,\ldots,\gamma^n)
$$
is not totally rigorous, although it is used by some authors who like working in coordinates.
The domain of $\phi$ is a subset of $S$, while the range of $(\gamma^1,\ldots,\gamma^n)$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^n$.
If $\phi$ is a chart and $(\xi^1,\ldots,\xi^n)$ is the associated coordinate system, then for a point $p\in S$ in the domain of $\phi$, we have the equality
$$
\phi(p) = (\xi^1(p),\ldots,\xi^n(p)).
$$
Put $p=\gamma(t)$, and you end up with
$$
\phi\circ\gamma(t) = (\xi^1(\gamma(t)),\ldots,\xi^n(\gamma(t)) = (\gamma^1(t),\ldots,\gamma^n(t)).
$$
Now, we have a function $\phi\circ \gamma \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^n$, whose components are the real functions $\gamma^i\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.
From usual differential calculus, you already know of to differentiate these functions: it is just
$$
(\phi\circ \gamma)'(t) = \left((\gamma^1)'(t),\ldots,(\gamma^n)'(t)\right).
$$
Now, if your question is about "how can I find $\gamma'(t)$?", then by the chain rule, you know that
$$
(\phi\circ \gamma)'(t) = d\phi_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t)),
$$
and since $d\phi_{\gamma(t)}$ is a linear isomorphism between $T_{\gamma(t)}S$ and $\Bbb R^n$, it follows that
$$
\gamma'(t) = \left(d\phi_{\gamma(t)}\right)^{-1} \left((\gamma^1)'(t),\ldots,(\gamma^n)'(t)\right).
$$